# My .htaccess file is not redirecting some pages . error 404

Tags: .htaccess, httpd.conf

```
# RewriteEngine On
# RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^admin
# RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^admin

#Change the base path below
# (i.e)if your using subfolders,type the folders path after = symbol example 
# (i.e)if your using only main domain means after = symbol add only forward slash /

SetEnvIf Request_URI "^.*" base_path=/

#Profile page URl rewritten
RewriteRule ^profile/([^/]*)$ %{ENV:BASE_PATH}profile.php?code=$1 [L]

#Company page URl rewritten
RewriteRule ^company/([^/]*)$ %{ENV:BASE_PATH}company-profile.php?code=$1 [L]

#Target Listing page URl rewritten
RewriteRule ^listings/([^/]*)$ %{ENV:BASE_PATH}target-listing.php?code=$1 [L]

#Ebook page URl rewritten
RewriteRule ^ebook/([^/]*)$ %{ENV:BASE_PATH}ebook.php?code=$1 [L]

#General page URl rewritten
RewriteRule ^promotion/([^/]*)$ %{ENV:BASE_PATH}template-default.php?code=$1 [L]

#Blog page URl rewritten
RewriteRule ^blog/([^/]*)$ %{ENV:BASE_PATH}blog-details.php?row=$1 [L]

#Event page URl rewritten
RewriteRule ^event/([^/]*)$ %{ENV:BASE_PATH}event-details.php?row=$1 [L]

#Product page URl rewritten
RewriteRule ^product/([^/]*)$ %{ENV:BASE_PATH}product-details.php?code=$1 [L]

#Listing page URl rewritten
RewriteRule ^listing/([^/]*)$ %{ENV:BASE_PATH}listing-details.php?code=$1 [L]

#Job Detail page URl rewritten
RewriteRule ^job/([^/]*)$ %{ENV:BASE_PATH}jobs/job-details.php?code=$1 [L]

#All Jobs page URl rewritten
RewriteRule ^all-jobs/([^/]*)$ %{ENV:BASE_PATH}jobs/all-jobs.php?category=$1 [L,QSA]

#Job Profile page URl rewritten
RewriteRule ^job-profile/([^/]*)$ %{ENV:BASE_PATH}jobs/job-profile.php?code=$1 [L]

#Service Expert Profile page URl rewritten
RewriteRule ^service-expert/([^/]*)$ %{ENV:BASE_PATH}service-experts/service-experts-profile.php?code=$1 [L]

#All Service Experts page URl rewritten
RewriteRule ^all-service-experts/([^/]*)$ %{ENV:BASE_PATH}service-experts/all-service-experts.php?category=$1 [L,QSA]

#News Details page URl rewritten
RewriteRule ^news-detail/([^/]*)$ %{ENV:BASE_PATH}news/news-details.php?code=$1 [L]

#All News page URl rewritten
RewriteRule ^news-all/([^/]*)$ %{ENV:BASE_PATH}news/news-all.php?category=$1 [L,QSA]

#Place Details page URl rewritten
RewriteRule ^place/([^/]*)$ %{ENV:BASE_PATH}places/place-details.php?code=$1 [L]

#All Listing page URl rewritten
RewriteRule ^all-listing/([^/]*)$ %{ENV:BASE_PATH}all-listing.php?category=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^all-listing/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ %{ENV:BASE_PATH}all-listing.php?category=$1&&subcategory=$2 [L]

#All Products page URl rewritten
RewriteRule ^all-products/([^/]*)$ %{ENV:BASE_PATH}all-products.php?category=$1 [L]

# DISABLE CACHING
# <IfModule mod_headers.c>
#     Header set Cache-Control "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
#     Header set Pragma "no-cache"
#     Header set Expires 0
# </IfModule>

# <FilesMatch "\.(css|flv|gif|htm|html|ico|jpe|jpeg|jpg|js|mp3|mp4|png|pdf|swf|txt)$">
#     <IfModule mod_expires.c>
#         ExpiresActive Off
#     </IfModule>
#     <IfModule mod_headers.c>
#         FileETag None
#         Header unset ETag
#         Header unset Pragma
#         Header unset Cache-Control
#         Header unset Last-Modified
#         Header set Pragma "no-cache"
#         Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
#         Header set Expires "Thu, 1 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT"
#     </IfModule>
# </FilesMatch>

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/html "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access 1 month"
</IfModule>

#RewriteEngine On
#RewriteRule ^demo/new/profile/([^\.]+)$ /demo/new/profile.php?profile=$1 [L]

# RewriteEngine On
# RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

I am getting a "Page not found" error, I have change the httpd to this conf. please help me find the error Please help

```
#
# This is the main Apache HTTP server configuration file.  It contains the
# configuration directives that give the server its instructions.
# See <URL:http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/> for detailed information.
# In particular, see 
# <URL:http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/directives.html>
# for a discussion of each configuration directive.
#
# See the httpd.conf(5) man page for more information on this configuration,
# and httpd.service(8) on using and configuring the httpd service.
#
# Do NOT simply read the instructions in here without understanding
# what they do.  They're here only as hints or reminders.  If you are unsure
# consult the online docs. You have been warned.  
#
# Configuration and logfile names: If the filenames you specify for many
# of the server's control files begin with "/" (or "drive:/" for Win32), the
# server will use that explicit path.  If the filenames do *not* begin
# with "/", the value of ServerRoot is prepended -- so 'log/access_log'
# with ServerRoot set to '/www' will be interpreted by the
# server as '/www/log/access_log', where as '/log/access_log' will be
# interpreted as '/log/access_log'.

#
# ServerRoot: The top of the directory tree under which the server's
# configuration, error, and log files are kept.
#
# Do not add a slash at the end of the directory path.  If you point
# ServerRoot at a non-local disk, be sure to specify a local disk on the
# Mutex directive, if file-based mutexes are used.  If you wish to share the
# same ServerRoot for multiple httpd daemons, you will need to change at
# least PidFile.
#
ServerRoot "/etc/httpd"

#
# Listen: Allows you to bind Apache to specific IP addresses and/or
# ports, instead of the default. See also the <VirtualHost>
# directive.
#
# Change this to Listen on specific IP addresses as shown below to 
# prevent Apache from glomming onto all bound IP addresses.
#
#Listen 12.34.56.78:80
Listen 80

#
# Dynamic Shared Object (DSO) Support
#
# To be able to use the functionality of a module which was built as a DSO you
# have to place corresponding `LoadModule' lines at this location so the
# directives contained in it are actually available _before_ they are used.
# Statically compiled modules (those listed by `httpd -l') do not need
# to be loaded here.
#
# Example:
# LoadModule foo_module modules/mod_foo.so
#
Include conf.modules.d/*.conf

#
# If you wish httpd to run as a different user or group, you must run
# httpd as root initially and it will switch.  
#
# User/Group: The name (or #number) of the user/group to run httpd as.
# It is usually good practice to create a dedicated user and group for
# running httpd, as with most system services.
#
User apache
Group apache

# 'Main' server configuration
#
# The directives in this section set up the values used by the 'main'
# server, which responds to any requests that aren't handled by a
# <VirtualHost> definition.  These values also provide defaults for
# any <VirtualHost> containers you may define later in the file.
#
# All of these directives may appear inside <VirtualHost> containers,
# in which case these default settings will be overridden for the
# virtual host being defined.
#

#
# ServerAdmin: Your address, where problems with the server should be
# e-mailed.  This address appears on some server-generated pages, such
# as error documents.  e.g. admin@your-domain.com
#
ServerAdmin root@localhost

#
# ServerName gives the name and port that the server uses to identify itself.
# This can often be determined automatically, but we recommend you specify
# it explicitly to prevent problems during startup.
#
# If your host doesn't have a registered DNS name, enter its IP address here.
#
#ServerName www.example.com:80

#
# Deny access to the entirety of your server's filesystem. You must
# explicitly permit access to web content directories in other 
# <Directory> blocks below.
#
<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all denied
</Directory>

#
# Note that from this point forward you must specifically allow
# particular features to be enabled - so if something's not working as
# you might expect, make sure that you have specifically enabled it
# below.
#

#
# DocumentRoot: The directory out of which you will serve your
# documents. By default, all requests are taken from this directory, but
# symbolic links and aliases may be used to point to other locations.
#
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"

#
# Relax access to content within /var/www.
#
<Directory "/var/www">
    
    AllowOverride All
    # Allow open access:
    Require all granted
</Directory>



# Further relax access to the default document root:
<Directory "/var/www/html">
    #
    # Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
    # or any combination of:
    #   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
    #
    # Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
    # doesn't give it to you.
    #
    # The Options directive is both complicated and important.  Please see
    # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#options
    # for more information.
    #
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks

    #
    # AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
    # It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
    #   Options FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
    #
    AllowOverride All
    #
    # Controls who can get stuff from this server.
    #
    Require all granted
</Directory>

#
# DirectoryIndex: sets the file that Apache will serve if a directory
# is requested.
#
<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.html
</IfModule>

#
# The following lines prevent .htaccess and .htpasswd files from being 
# viewed by Web clients. 
#
<Files ".ht*">
    Require all denied
</Files>

#
# ErrorLog: The location of the error log file.
# If you do not specify an ErrorLog directive within a <VirtualHost>
# container, error messages relating to that virtual host will be
# logged here.  If you *do* define an error logfile for a <VirtualHost>
# container, that host's errors will be logged there and not here.
#
ErrorLog "logs/error_log"

#
# LogLevel: Control the number of messages logged to the error_log.
# Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
# alert, emerg.
#
LogLevel warn

<IfModule log_config_module>
    #
    # The following directives define some format nicknames for use with
    # a CustomLog directive (see below).
    #
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common

    <IfModule logio_module>
        # You need to enable mod_logio.c to use %I and %O
        LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %I %O" combinedio
    </IfModule>

    #
    # The location and format of the access logfile (Common Logfile Format).
    # If you do not define any access logfiles within a <VirtualHost>
    # container, they will be logged here.  Contrariwise, if you *do*
    # define per-<VirtualHost> access logfiles, transactions will be
    # logged therein and *not* in this file.
    #
    #CustomLog "logs/access_log" common

    #
    # If you prefer a logfile with access, agent, and referer information
    # (Combined Logfile Format) you can use the following directive.
    #
    CustomLog "logs/access_log" combined
</IfModule>

<IfModule alias_module>
    #
    # Redirect: Allows you to tell clients about documents that used to 
    # exist in your server's namespace, but do not anymore. The client 
    # will make a new request for the document at its new location.
    # Example:
    # Redirect permanent /foo http://www.example.com/bar

    #
    # Alias: Maps web paths into filesystem paths and is used to
    # access content that does not live under the DocumentRoot.
    # Example:
    # Alias /webpath /full/filesystem/path
    #
    # If you include a trailing / on /webpath then the server will
    # require it to be present in the URL.  You will also likely
    # need to provide a <Directory> section to allow access to
    # the filesystem path.

    #
    # ScriptAlias: This controls which directories contain server scripts. 
    # ScriptAliases are essentially the same as Aliases, except that
    # documents in the target directory are treated as applications and
    # run by the server when requested rather than as documents sent to the
    # client.  The same rules about trailing "/" apply to ScriptAlias
    # directives as to Alias.
    #
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/var/www/cgi-bin/"

</IfModule>

#
# "/var/www/cgi-bin" should be changed to whatever your ScriptAliased
# CGI directory exists, if you have that configured.
#
<Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<IfModule mime_module>
    #
    # TypesConfig points to the file containing the list of mappings from
    # filename extension to MIME-type.
    #
    TypesConfig /etc/mime.types

    #
    # AddType allows you to add to or override the MIME configuration
    # file specified in TypesConfig for specific file types.
    #
    #AddType application/x-gzip .tgz
    #
    # AddEncoding allows you to have certain browsers uncompress
    # information on the fly. Note: Not all browsers support this.
    #
    #AddEncoding x-compress .Z
    #AddEncoding x-gzip .gz .tgz
    #
    # If the AddEncoding directives above are commented-out, then you
    # probably should define those extensions to indicate media types:
    #
    AddType application/x-compress .Z
    AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz

    #
    # AddHandler allows you to map certain file extensions to "handlers":
    # actions unrelated to filetype. These can be either built into the server
    # or added with the Action directive (see below)
    #
    # To use CGI scripts outside of ScriptAliased directories:
    # (You will also need to add "ExecCGI" to the "Options" directive.)
    #
    #AddHandler cgi-script .cgi

    # For type maps (negotiated resources):
    #AddHandler type-map var

    #
    # Filters allow you to process content before it is sent to the client.
    #
    # To parse .shtml files for server-side includes (SSI):
    # (You will also need to add "Includes" to the "Options" directive.)
    #
    AddType text/html .shtml
    AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml
</IfModule>

#
# Specify a default charset for all content served; this enables
# interpretation of all content as UTF-8 by default.  To use the 
# default browser choice (ISO-8859-1), or to allow the META tags
# in HTML content to override this choice, comment out this
# directive:
#
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

<IfModule mime_magic_module>
    #
    # The mod_mime_magic module allows the server to use various hints from the
    # contents of the file itself to determine its type.  The MIMEMagicFile
    # directive tells the module where the hint definitions are located.
    #
    MIMEMagicFile conf/magic
</IfModule>

#
# Customizable error responses come in three flavors:
# 1) plain text 2) local redirects 3) external redirects
#
# Some examples:
#ErrorDocument 500 "The server made a boo boo."
#ErrorDocument 404 /missing.html
#ErrorDocument 404 "/cgi-bin/missing_handler.pl"
#ErrorDocument 402 http://www.example.com/subscription_info.html
#

#
# EnableMMAP and EnableSendfile: On systems that support it, 
# memory-mapping or the sendfile syscall may be used to deliver
# files.  This usually improves server performance, but must
# be turned off when serving from networked-mounted 
# filesystems or if support for these functions is otherwise
# broken on your system.
# Defaults if commented: EnableMMAP On, EnableSendfile Off
#
#EnableMMAP off
EnableSendfile on

# Supplemental configuration
#
# Load config files in the "/etc/httpd/conf.d" directory, if any.
IncludeOptional conf.d/*.conf
SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3 -TLSv1 -TLSv1.1
SSLCipherSuite ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
ServerTokens Prod
ServerSignature Off
TraceEnable Off
<VirtualHost 65.25.15.58:80 [2a02:4780:12:144d::1]:80>
    ServerName abcxyz.cloud
    ServerAlias www.abcxyz.cloud
    ServerAlias mail.abcxyz.cloud
    DocumentRoot /home/abcxyz/public_html
    ErrorLog /var/log/virtualmin/abcxyz.cloud_error_log
    CustomLog /var/log/virtualmin/abcxyz.cloud_access_log combined
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /home/abcxyz/cgi-bin/
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.php4 index.php5 index.htm index.html
    <Directory "/home/abcxyz/public_html">
        Options -Indexes +IncludesNOEXEC +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch 
        Require all granted
        AllowOverride All Options=ExecCGI,Includes,IncludesNOEXEC,Indexes,MultiViews,SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    </Directory>
    <Directory /home/abcxyz/cgi-bin>
        Require all granted
        AllowOverride All Options=ExecCGI,Includes,IncludesNOEXEC,Indexes,MultiViews,SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        SetHandler proxy:unix:/var/fcgiwrap/16918394802861.sock/socket|fcgi://localhost
        ProxyFCGISetEnvIf true SCRIPT_FILENAME "/home/abcxyz%{reqenv:SCRIPT_NAME}"
    </Directory>
    ProxyPass /.well-known !
    RemoveHandler .php
    RemoveHandler .php7.2
    <FilesMatch \.php$>
        SetHandler proxy:unix:/var/php-fpm/16918394802861.sock|fcgi://127.0.0.1
    </FilesMatch>
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost 65.25.15.58:443 [2a02:4780:12:144d::1]:443>
    ServerName abcxyz.cloud
    ServerAlias www.abcxyz.cloud
    ServerAlias mail.abcxyz.cloud
    DocumentRoot /home/abcxyz/public_html
    ErrorLog /var/log/virtualmin/abcxyz.cloud_error_log
    CustomLog /var/log/virtualmin/abcxyz.cloud_access_log combined
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /home/abcxyz/cgi-bin/
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.php4 index.php5 index.htm index.html
    <Directory /home/abcxyz/public_html>
        Options -Indexes +IncludesNOEXEC +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch 
        Require all granted
        AllowOverride All Options=ExecCGI,Includes,IncludesNOEXEC,Indexes,MultiViews,SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    </Directory>
    <Directory /home/abcxyz/cgi-bin>
        Require all granted
        AllowOverride All Options=ExecCGI,Includes,IncludesNOEXEC,Indexes,MultiViews,SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        SetHandler proxy:unix:/var/fcgiwrap/16918394802861.sock/socket|fcgi://localhost
        ProxyFCGISetEnvIf true SCRIPT_FILENAME "/home/abcxyz%{reqenv:SCRIPT_NAME}"
    </Directory>
    ProxyPass /.well-known !
    RemoveHandler .php
    RemoveHandler .php7.2
    <FilesMatch \.php$>
        SetHandler proxy:unix:/var/php-fpm/16918394802861.sock|fcgi://127.0.0.1
    </FilesMatch>
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/virtualmin/16918394802861/ssl.cert
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/virtualmin/16918394802861/ssl.key
    SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3 -TLSv1 -TLSv1.1
    SSLCACertificateFile /etc/ssl/virtualmin/16918394802861/ssl.ca
</VirtualHost>
```

in my local server it works fine but when i try in my hostinger server with almalinux i am getting this error. SElinix is disabled. .htaccess file is working , because if i change anything in .htaccess my webpage stop loading . so i dont no what to do next

Comment: the files i public_html folder doesnt load with .htaccess . but files under sub folder load with .htaccess file.

Answer (score 0):

In your current `.htaccess` configuration, you have rewrite rules that redirect URLs to corresponding PHP files with the .php extension. While this setup might work seamlessly on your local server, it can lead to conflicts on other servers due to the **identical** naming of URLs and PHP files.

For instance, take the example of RewriteRule `^all-products/([^/]*)$ %{ENV:BASE_PATH}all-products.php?category=$1 [L]`. This rule redirects a URL like `all-products` to `all-products.php`, where **the names match exactly**. This alignment can cause issues on certain servers that handle conflicts differently from your local environment.

To resolve this potential problem, you have a few options:

- Rename Routing Names: You could choose to rename your routing names or modify them slightly to ensure there is no direct overlap with PHP filenames. This approach might require adjusting your application's URLs and references.
- Rename PHP Files: Alternatively, you could rename your PHP files to something different from your routing names. This way, there won't be a direct name clash between URLs and PHP files.
- Organize PHP Files: **The recommended and simpler solution** is to create a designated folder, such as `"scripts"`, and move all your PHP files into it. Then, update your .htaccess rules to include the folder name before each PHP filename. For example, the rule for `all-products` would become

```
RewriteRule ^all-products/([^/]*)$ %{ENV:BASE_PATH}scripts/all-products.php?category=$1 [L].
```

By adopting this approach, you avoid naming conflicts between URLs and PHP files..

Comment: [Generative AI (e.g., ChatGPT) is banned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned)